# button action inside forEach always returns last object

Tags: swiftui, foreach

I have a ForEach loop where I am creating a CardView inside of a button. When the button is pressed I set it as selected and do stuff. The items are displaying properly but when I tapped the item, the selectedCard is always set to the last item in my array. I am not sure how to fix this. I've seen this in other examples and they seem to work so I don't know what I'm missing.

```
ForEach(0..<viewModel.cards.count, id: \.self) { index in
   let card = viewModel.cards[index]
   Button {
      viewModel.selectedCard = card
   } label: {
      CardView(card: card)
         .padding(.horizontal, 35)
   }
                      
}

class Card: ObservableObject {
   @Published var name: String
   @Published var zIndex: Int
   
   init(name: String, zIndex: Int = 0) {
      self.name = name
      self.zIndex = zIndex
   }
}
```

I tried adding an id like this: let id = UUID() and making my Card a struct and Identifiable and Hashable and changing the id: but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Change `id: \.self` to `id: \.id`, does that work?

Comment: The identifiable approach with struct is much better, unfortunately you don’t show it.

Comment: Why do you have a view model?